# Carrierwave uploads image locally, not to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I've configured Carrierwave+Fog to work with Amazon S3. The problem I have is that everything is created in the public folder of my project and isn't uploaded to S3. The thumb and the dir are OK, is only the placement of the image that is not working.

My uploader:

```
    class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
    storage :fog
    def store_dir
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end
    version :thumb do
      process :resize_to_fit => [200, 200]
    end
    def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
    end
end
```

fog.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id => 'xxx',
    :aws_secret_access_key => 'yyy',
    :region => 'eu-west-1'
  }

  config.fog_directory = 'your_bucket_here'
  config.fog_public = true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000'} 
end
```

The class that uses it:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  mount_uploader :remote_file, ImageUploader
end
```

And the controller code:

```
    i = Image.new
    i.save
    i.remote_file = params[:image]

    render :json => {:response => i.remote_file.url}
```

The response is:
{"response":"/uploads/tmp/1387464252-27678-6793/logo11w.png"}

And the image is created inside the public dir of the rails project.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

CarrierWave performs the upload with [ActiveRecord before_save and after_save callbacks](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb#L28). In your controller, set the `remote_file` before you call `save`:

```
i = Image.new
i.remote_file = params[:image]
i.save
```